# Writing DataFrame to Cassandra, getting CassandraCatalogException "Attempting to write to C* Table but missing primary keys columns"

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, databricks, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to write a csv file stored in an Azure Blob storage in a cassandra table. I'm on Databricks using pyspark.

On theroy I have no problem on creating the table and write some dataframe, both creating "by hand" and taken by the the blob storage. In both cases, the datafram is really small, one or two rows.

When I try to write the "big" dataframe (about 50k rows) I recieve an error by the cell running the command.

Pyspark command:

```
(
 df_csv
  .write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .mode('append')
  .options(table=<table name>, keyspace=<keyspace>)
  .save()
)
```

Error received

> com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalogException: Attempting to write to C* Table but missing

I'm on com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12:3.2.0 drivers for cassandra.

I've the feeleng that the error message is not complete, but of curse I cannot be sure about that.
I already checked if there are differences in column name between the dataframe and the cassandra table, but there aren't.

For testing the code I made thi s simple write process:

```
department1 = Row(id='1', name='Computer Science')
department2 = Row(id='2', name='Mechanical Engineering')
departments = [department1, department2]


df1 = spark.createDataFrame(departments)

'''spark configuration'''
spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", <host-ip>)
spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", <username>)
spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", <password>)


cassandra_session.execute('create table transactions(id int PRIMARY KEY, NAME varchar)')

df1.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").mode('append').options(table="transactions", keyspace=<keyspace>).save()
```

and like I said before, no problem at all with this, even if i try to append a dataframe made by using a csv in the blob storage

Comment: please post the full error

Answer (score 0):

The `CassandraCatalogException` you posted indicates that the primary key column(s) is missing from the DataFrame ([source `CassandraWriteBuilder.scala`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v3.2.0/connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/datasource/CassandraWriteBuilder.scala#L41-L45)).

You stated that your code works for a small dataset but fails for a large DF with 50K rows. I suspect that at least one (or more) row(s) in your DF is missing data so it fails when saving it to Cassandra.

You will need to manually inspect the contents of the DataFrame. One way to do this is to export the CSV so you can review it. Once you've identified the offending record(s), you can fix them and try to run your app again. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for edit the title. I will give it a try, and I also think this could be relate to some non-ascii character inside the DF.

Comment: I made some progress and I found that the problem are the column names: If I create the table with column named <column_name> I receive the error; if I create the table with column named <"column_name"> there is no error and the table is wirrte correctly. But with this solution I cannot make a query without the "" even directly on cassandra.